# Can I intercept calls for my WSDL on Glassfish (or on any app server)?

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, listener, servlet-filters

I've created a Java web service using the `@WebService` annotation and deployed the service to a Glassfish server that lives behind a proxy server.

The problem is when someone accesses our WSDL and looks at the service endpoint address location they see

```
http://app server url/service...
```

instead of

```
http://proxy server url/service...
```

I'd like to have the proxy server URL returned in the service endpoint address location of the WSDL instead of the app server url.

What I'm wondering is, can I write a Filter or a Listener to listen for requests to the WSDL, then modify the WSDL service endpoint address with the proxy server URL?  What might be the recommended way to do this - I was thinking a Filter is the best choice, but wasn't 100% sure?

BTW - I thought there might be a simple setting in Glassfish to do this, but [I haven't been able to locate one that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142924/override-glassfish-generated-wsdl-service-endpoint-address).

Comment: Did you tried using the `wsdlLocation` attribute in the `@WebService` annotation? You can maybe specify the WSDL to return to the client.

Comment: CXF has a feature specifically for this.

Comment: @ewernli - Thanks, but the container (Glassfish) still seems the overwrite the endpoint address.  It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @bmargulies - CXF looks cool, but I don't think we'll be able to integrate that framework at this time.  Thanks though, I'll definitely want to come back and look at that in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the filter approach and here's what I came up with.  It seems to work.

I've included the code for my `Filter`'s `doFilter` method.  I also wrote a custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, but that implementation was pretty straightforward.

the [Apache reverse-proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) adds the `x-forwarded-host` value to the HTTP header (and is the name I use to replace the app servers name).  Another alternative I thought of was to place the proxy server's address as a property on the app server and grab that.  Ultimately, I thought this was a cleaner way to go.

```
/*
 * Replace the server URL with the proxy server URL when called from a proxy server 
 */
@Override
public void doFilter(
    ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    WsdlResponseWrapper myResponse = new WsdlResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, myResponse);
    boolean isResponseOutputStream = myResponse.getOutputStreamContent().length > 0;

    /*
     * The servlet response sent into this method only allows access to
     * getOutputStream or getWriter, not both. It will throw an
     * exception if an attempt is made to to access both.
     * 
     * If this reason, I'm checking the output stream first and writing
     * that content if it exists, then printing to the writer only if
     * the output stream is empty.
     */
    StringBuffer responseBuffer;
    if (isResponseOutputStream) {
         responseBuffer = new StringBuffer(new String(myResponse.getOutputStreamContent()));
    } else {
        responseBuffer = new StringBuffer(myResponse.getWriterContent());
    }

    // Change the URL when called from a proxy server
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String requestedHostname = httpServletRequest.getHeader("x-forwarded-host");
        if ((null != requestedHostname) && !requestedHostname.isEmpty()) {
            String myHostname = httpServletRequest.getHeader("host");
            int myPort = httpServletRequest.getLocalPort();

            // change the hostname
            int index = responseBuffer.indexOf(myHostname);
            int length = myHostname.length();
            while (index > -1) {
                responseBuffer.replace(index, index+length, requestedHostname);
                index = responseBuffer.indexOf(myHostname);
            }

            // remove the port
            String portString = ":" + myPort;
            length = portString.length();
            index = responseBuffer.indexOf(portString);
            while (index > -1) {
                responseBuffer.replace(index, index+length, "");
                index = responseBuffer.indexOf(portString);
            }
        }
    }

    // forward the response
    if (isResponseOutputStream) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(responseBuffer.toString().getBytes());
    } else {
        response.getWriter().print(responseBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The only extra thing I needed was to call `response.resetBuffer();` before writing to the response output stream. Both the former and the modified response payloads would be returned otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

From [Javaboutique article on servlet-filters](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/)

```
public final class TimerFilter implements Filter 
{

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                      ServletResponse response,
                      FilterChain chain)
     throws IOException, ServletException 
 {

     long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
     long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Time to execute request: " + (stopTime - startTime) + 
         " milliseconds");

 }
...
```

the call to chain.doFilter will call the normal servlet in your case (I'm assuming the @WebService is provided through a servlet API), and you can then read the result from the original web service, modify it, and pass it back to your own client.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using a **web service registry** for that?

The [glassfish](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4335/gbbja?a=view) doc about web service registry says:

> If you are using a load balancer,
>   enter the Load Balancer host name,
>   port number, and the SSL port number.
>   If you are publishing the web service
>   to an external registry, where the
>   WSDL can be found over the internet,
>   these options will replace the
>   hostname and port name specified in
>   the WSDL to the one of the load
>   balancer.

So that should work for your proxy as well.

Here are two resources that might be interesting: the [glassfish ws management](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ws-mgmt/wsmgmthome.html) page, an article aobut how to [set up the registry](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/ws_mgmt3.html#7).

I never used the registry myself, and agree that it's a bit heavy-weighted for what you want to achieve, but it seems to be a possible way to publish web service endpoint information for consumers.

Answer (score 0):

If Apache is your proxy, you can try doing what I did, which is really simple.  Apache causes the problem (sort-of), so use Apache to fix it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136594/2666055